# Visual Studio closes solutions immediately after upgrading to 17.2

Tags: visual-studio

Yesterday I upgraded Visual Studio 2022 from 17.1.x to 17.2. Now, when I try to open a solution, I can see the the Solution Explorer being populated with the projects, and files I had open previously are opened as well. After a second or so, the solution closes.

This happens with most, but not all solutions, but I haven't been able to find a pattern. There was one I that could finally open once, but today it closes immediately again. When I create a new solution and add a project, VS will also (sometimes) close the solution.

What I tried (but didn't fix the problem):

- Run VS in safe mode, i.e. `devenv /SafeMode`
- Reset VS, i.e. `devenv /ResetSettings`
- Repair the installation using Visual Studio Installer
- Removed *some* extensions. Admittedly, I may have to remove all to be sure the rpoblem is not with any of those
- Run VS with logging. The logfile shows some errors about not being able to load ChromeDebugAdapter and EdgeDebugAdapter, but I have no idea how to fix those. The exact error message is below.

Anyone have an idea on how to proceed?

**Update**
My problem seems to be the same as [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-1720-solution-closes-immediatel/10038489). I'll monitor that thread, and post an answer here if it is fixed.

---

`Unable to load extension at: C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WEBCLIENT\DIAGNOSTICS\CHROMEDEBUGADAPTER\. Exception text: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InvalidExtensionManifestException: This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest&apos;s format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted. ---&gt; System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (12, 5). ---&gt; System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: The element &apos;Identifier&apos; in namespace &apos;http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010&apos; has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: &apos;SupportedProducts&apos; in namespace &apos;http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-schema/2010&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(ValidationEventHandler eventHandler, Object sender, XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.InternalValidateEndElement(XmlSchemaInfo schemaInfo, Object typedValue)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessEndElementEvent()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementString()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.XmlSerializationReaderVsix.Read5_VsixIdentifier(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.XmlSerializationReaderVsix.Read12_Vsix(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.XmlSerializationReaderVsix.Read13_Vsix()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionImpl.ReadVSIXManifest(XmlReader xmlReader)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionImpl.ReadManifest(Stream manifestStream)&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionImpl.ReadManifest(Stream manifestStream)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionImpl..ctor(String path)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstalledExtensionImpl..ctor(String vsixManifestPath, IEngineHost engineHost, Boolean installedPerMachine, CultureInfo preferredCulture, IList1 extensionPackVsixIds, IList1 packageGuids)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.InstalledExtensionImpl..ctor(String vsixManifestPath, IEngineHost engineHost, Boolean installedPerMachine, CultureInfo preferredCulture, IList1 packageGuids)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ScanModule.TryLoadExtension(ExtensionLocations location, String fullPath, String normalizedPath, InstalledExtensionImpl&amp; installedExtension, Int32 retryCount, Int32 retryDelay, Int32 attempts).`

Comment: You will have to give us more information about the solutions themselves.  If you create a new solution does it still close? Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374907/the-visual-studio-2022-error-failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-additional-informa) solution

Comment: Be sure you remove any older versions of any additional VS components

Comment: @Ramhound When I create a new solution it also closes sometimes, that is already in my question. The question you linked to is different, I don't get any errors, the solution just closes silently. Which *additional VS components* are you referring to?

Comment: The Visual Studio components that you installed. I have no other description, with the Visual Studio installer, you can install different components allowing you to create different types of projects/solutions. You do have an error, it might not be displayed, but your log file indicates it’s an exception. What type of project are you loading, be as specific, as possible

Comment: “While we work on a fix for this, you should be able to do a manual workaround and rename your git remote to “origin” instead of its current name.” - Try that solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an update

And in this version 12.2.5 seems fixed issue that fail canning for extensions

> Fixed an issue where a SxS install of VS2022 and VS2015 (or older) causes VS to fail scanning for extensions.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.2.4

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1131688)